# React DOM reconciliation coupled with an Intersection Observer is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

**Update: This is a bug in Chrome and Edge. The code works just fine in Firefox.**

Rendering components based off an array and then reordering the array causes the Intersection Observer to improperly register which elements are currently in the viewport... or maybe it's a react DOM reconciliation issue?

Steps To Reproduce

In the code sandbox linked below, scroll down so that boxes four and (at least partially) five are in the viewport.

Click REORDER at the top left of the page. This will cause a swap of boxes four and eight, so now eight is in the viewport and four is not.

You will notice that box five is now goldenrod, meaning that it is not considered to be in the viewport (a class is added to change the background-color).

You can scroll further so that box four is at the top of the page and upon clicking "REORDER" you'll see that it is in fact every box after box four that is now goldenrod, again indicating that it is not in the viewport.

What gives?

Check out the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-firefly-w5vqm8?file=/src/box.js).

I also [filed a bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/27448) with the react team.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51402840/25507) suggests that this is a limitation of the IntersectionObserver API (it responds to scrolling / viewport changes but not to page mutations) rather than a React issue.

Comment: You can work around it for this example by recreating the IntersectionObserver whenever you reorder the list. You could do this by creating a basic string prop on box called something like `sortKey` and change this based on your current sort method (init / diff) pass this through to the useEffect dependency array creating your intersectionObserver and you have your desired result.

Comment: @JoshKelley I'm not sure I agree with the suggestion that scrolling is what it relies upon. The very first sentence of the Intersection Observer API: "The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport."

Comment: @JacobSmit yea we've already got a work around, and that's simply to add to the dependency array of the hook we've created to observe... which feels hacky.

Comment: @BradEvans - I could easily be wrong (and, now that I'm re-reading the spec, I don't see anything restricting it to scrolling). But the question I linked to seems to demonstrate that it fails to fire for (some) page mutations. I'm wondering now if this is simply an area with browser bugs (as you found).